# List Elements with flex working rare at Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, flexbox, microsoft-edge

I have a menu, with a toggle function (js).
The thing is that at chrome works fine, but at MEdge it's like not respect the parent width.
I try 
    display: table; or inline-table, also overflow-wrap: break-word;
But nothing works T_T

chrome its ok;
[image]

edge not;
[image]

I re-created it here **JS Fiddle -** https://jsfiddle.net/chocoXXL/9Lz1sb72

```js
$(".nav_menu li ul").hide();

$(".nav_menu li ").click(function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
     
 if($(this).children('ul').length == 0)
 {
    $(".nav_menu li ul").hide();
    var href = $('a', this).attr('href');
    window.location = href;
    
    console.log(href);
 }
    if ($(this).parents('.active').length) {
      $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp();
      
    }
    else {
      //$(this).siblings().children('ul').slideUp();
      $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp();
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #6f6c69;
}
header {
  background-color: #FFF8DC;
}
.box_max {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
}
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
}
#box_logo a {
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 5px;
    /* ackground-image: url('../images/logo.png'); */
    background-size: 100%;
}
#box_logo a img {
    height: 100%;
}
.btn_header_box {
 display: flex;
    margin: auto 0;
}
#btn_go_search.searching, #btn_no_search.searching {
    right: 100%;
}

#btn_go_search, #btn_no_search {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
#le_burger, #le_lupa {
    display: none;
}
button.btn_zoom i {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
.menu-le_menu-container {
    height: 100%;
}
#box_out_header {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
ul.nav_menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: normal;
    height: 100%;
}
ul.nav_menu li {
    list-style: none;
 /*display: list-item;*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
}
ul.nav_menu li a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4a443f;
    /*font-weight: 500;*/
    transition: 0.2s all cubic-bezier(0.8, 0.2, 0.57, 1.01);
    border: 2px solid rgba(221, 153, 0, 0);
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
ul.nav_menu li a:hover {
    color: #dd9900;
}
ul.nav_menu>li {
    background-color: blue;
    display: table;
}
ul.nav_menu>li>a {
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 22px;
}
.nav_menu li li a {
    background-color: #eae8e6;
}
.nav_menu li li li a {
    background-color: #dad2cd;
}
.nav_menu li li li li a {
    background-color: #cabeb4;
}
.nav_menu li li li li li a {
    background-color: #bfae9f;
}
.nav_menu li li li li li li a {
    background-color: #b9a089;
}
.nav_menu li li li li a:hover {
    color: white;
}
.nav_menu li li li li li a:hover {
    color: white;
}
.nav_menu li li li li li li a:hover {
    color: white;
}

#le_buscar {
    margin: auto 0;
    border: 2px solid rgba(221, 153, 0, 0);
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 22px;
}

#le_buscar p {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#le_buscar:hover * {
    color: #dd9900;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="box_max flipInX">
    <div id="box_logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/87x80/000/fff "></a>
    </div>

    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="menu-le_menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-le_menu" class="nav_menu">
                <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-27">
                    <a href="#">
                        <d>Inicio</d>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-7 current_page_item menu-item-26">
                    <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                        <d>Nosotros</d>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-453" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-453">
                    <a href="#">
                        <d>Equipos</d>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu" style="">
                        <li id="menu-item-460" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-460">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Almacenamiento de Alimento</d>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                                <li id="menu-item-468" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-468">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Silos</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-467" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-467">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Pesaje y Transporte</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-462" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-462">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Huevos</d>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                                <li id="menu-item-475" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-475">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Incubación</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-474" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-474">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Clasificadoras</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-476" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-476">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Marcadoras</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-461" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-461">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Crianza</d>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                                <li id="menu-item-1285" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1285">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Comederos</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-469" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-469">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Bebederos</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-473" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-473">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Nidos Automáticos</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-472" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-472">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Galpones</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-1278" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1278">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Climatización</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-463" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-463">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Procesamiento</d>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                                <li id="menu-item-480" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-480">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Matanza</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-479" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-479">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Evisceración</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-478" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-478">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Enfriamiento</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-481" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-481">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Pesaje y clasificación</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-482" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-482">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Trozado</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-477" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-477">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Deshuese</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-464" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-464">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Rendering</d>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                                <li id="menu-item-489" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-489">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Transportadores</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-487" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-487">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Tolvas</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-488" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-488">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Trituradores</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-563" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-563">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Tratamiento de Aguas</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-454" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-454">
                    <a href="#">
                        <d>Implementos</d>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                        <li id="menu-item-455" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-455">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Cajas Plásticas</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-456" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-456">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Paletas Plásticas</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-457" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-457">
                    <a href="#">
                        <d>Repuestos</d>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                        <li id="menu-item-459" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-459">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Remover</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-1345" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1345">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Troles</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-1343" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1343">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Cadenas</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-466" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-466">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Ganchos</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-526" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-526">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Otros</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25">
                    <a href="#">
                        <d>Noticias</d>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24">
                    <a href="#">
                        <d>Contacto</d>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>
    <div id="le_buscar">
        <p>Buscar </p>
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: The `.sub-menu` class gets a bigger width in Edge for some reason, which in turn expands its parent container, in this case the `.menu-item` that holds the "Equipos" link. Chrome is doing that as well but to a lesser degree. I also think you should be setting the toggled `.sub-menu` to absolute, else the content below the navigation will be pushed down, unless that's what you want. Your current issue will be fixed if you do, though, you will just need to center the absolutely positioned element horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check your code and I made the test with **Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0**.

I can see the issue in the MS Edge browser.

I found that if we remove the below CSS code then the issue can be solved.

```
ul.nav_menu>li {
    background-color: blue;
    display: table;
}
```

See the result:

[image]

Further, you can try to modify your code based on your requirements.

Comment: True, but that reveals another issue, that u can click the blank area of the next item.
look here: https://imgur.com/a/robot5G

Answer (score 0):

@chris-w and @emontielg guided me to the perfection.
First I need to set the container width, so EDGE can work with the right dimension (I guess).
So I remove all the diferents diplays (keeping in mind the flexbox), then just add "align-self: flex-start;" to the first LI element.
BOOM MAGIC :D

P.S. the `<d>` it is something WordPress adds on.

Here is the corrected code **JS Fiddle -** https://jsfiddle.net/chocoXXL/27bqukzm/)

```
<header class="box_max flipInX">
    <div id="box_logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/87x80/000/fff "></a>
    </div>

    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="menu-le_menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-le_menu" class="nav_menu">
                <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-27">
                    <a href="#">
                        <d>Inicio</d>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-7 current_page_item menu-item-26">
                    <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                        <d>Nosotros</d>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-453" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-453">
                    <a href="#">
                        <d>Equipos</d>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu" style="">
                        <li id="menu-item-460" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-460">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Almacenamiento de Alimento</d>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                                <li id="menu-item-468" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-468">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Silos</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-467" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-467">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Pesaje y Transporte</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-462" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-462">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Huevos</d>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                                <li id="menu-item-475" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-475">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Incubación</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-474" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-474">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Clasificadoras</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-476" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-476">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Marcadoras</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-461" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-461">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Crianza</d>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                                <li id="menu-item-1285" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1285">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Comederos</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-469" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-469">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Bebederos</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-473" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-473">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Nidos Automáticos</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-472" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-472">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Galpones</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-1278" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1278">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Climatización</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-463" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-463">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Procesamiento</d>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                                <li id="menu-item-480" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-480">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Matanza</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-479" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-479">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Evisceración</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-478" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-478">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Enfriamiento</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-481" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-481">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Pesaje y clasificación</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-482" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-482">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Trozado</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-477" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-477">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Deshuese</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-464" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-464">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Rendering</d>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                                <li id="menu-item-489" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-489">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Transportadores</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-487" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-487">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Tolvas</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-488" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-488">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <d>Trituradores</d>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-563" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-563">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Tratamiento de Aguas</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-454" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-454">
                    <a href="#">
                        <d>Implementos</d>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                        <li id="menu-item-455" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-455">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Cajas Plásticas</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-456" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-456">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Paletas Plásticas</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-457" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-457">
                    <a href="#">
                        <d>Repuestos</d>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                        <li id="menu-item-459" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-459">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Remover</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-1345" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1345">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Troles</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-1343" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-1343">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Cadenas</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-466" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-466">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Ganchos</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-526" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-526">
                            <a href="#">
                                <d>Otros</d>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25">
                    <a href="#">
                        <d>Noticias</d>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24">
                    <a href="#">
                        <d>Contacto</d>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>
    <div id="le_buscar">
        <p>Buscar </p>
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</header>
```

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #6f6c69;
}
header {
  background-color: #FFF8DC;
}
.box_max {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
}
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
align-items: flex-start;
}
#box_logo a {
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 5px;
    /* ackground-image: url('../images/logo.png'); */
    background-size: 100%;
}
#box_logo a img {
    height: 100%;
}
.btn_header_box {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto 0;
}
#btn_go_search.searching, #btn_no_search.searching {
    right: 100%;
}

#btn_go_search, #btn_no_search {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
#le_burger, #le_lupa {
    display: none;
}
button.btn_zoom i {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
.menu-le_menu-container {
    height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#box_out_header {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
}
ul.nav_menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: normal;
    height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.nav_menu>li {
    background-color: blue;
    list-style: none;
    /*display: table;
    position: relative;*/
/*  width: 100%;*/
  align-self: flex-start;
}
ul.nav_menu>li>a {
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 22px;
}
ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style: none;
    /*display: list-item;*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
}
ul.nav_menu li a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4a443f;
    /*font-weight: 500;*/
    transition: 0.2s all cubic-bezier(0.8, 0.2, 0.57, 1.01);
    border: 2px solid rgba(221, 153, 0, 0);
  /*overflow-wrap: break-word;*/
  /*word-break: keep-all;*/
}
ul.nav_menu li a:hover {
    color: #dd9900;
}
.nav_menu li li a {
    background-color: #eae8e6;
}
.nav_menu li li li a {
    background-color: #dad2cd;
}
.nav_menu li li li li a {
    background-color: #cabeb4;
}
.nav_menu li li li li li a {
    background-color: #bfae9f;
}
.nav_menu li li li li li li a {
    background-color: #b9a089;
}
.nav_menu li li li li a:hover {
    color: white;
}
.nav_menu li li li li li a:hover {
    color: white;
}
.nav_menu li li li li li li a:hover {
    color: white;
}

#le_buscar {
    margin: auto 0;
    border: 2px solid rgba(221, 153, 0, 0);
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 22px;
}

#le_buscar p {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#le_buscar:hover * {
    color: #dd9900;
}
.sub-menu {
    position: relative;
}
```

```
/*HEELO*/

$(".nav_menu li ul").hide();

$(".nav_menu li ").click(function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();

    if($(this).children('ul').length == 0)
    {
       $(".nav_menu li ul").hide();
       var href = $('a', this).attr('href');
       window.location = href;

       console.log(href);
    }
    if ($(this).parents('.active').length) {
      $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp();

    }
    else {
      //$(this).siblings().children('ul').slideUp();
      $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp();
    }
});


$("#box_logo ").click(function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
      //$('.nav_menu ul').not(this).slideUp();
  $('.nav_menu ul').slideUp();
});

$("body ").not(this).click(function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
      //$('.nav_menu ul').not(this).slideUp();
  $('.nav_menu ul').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.